# a nonlinear ode with an quotient

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I'm curious about the nonlinear ODEs with an quotient including dependent variable : $$y''(x)+\frac{Ay(x)x}{1+y(x)}+Bx=0$$
Could you give me a clue on solving this equation explicitly?

Comment: Did you create this ODE yourself? Because in general ODEs have no explicit solution. Well if you found it in a textbook it is another problem...

Comment: @Sebastien B yes, I modified the question form $$y''(x)+Ay(x)x+B=0.$$ After your response, I see that it was not clever:( Is such a solution only numerically possible?

Comment: About your equation $y''(x)+\frac{Ay(x)x}{1+y(x)}+Bx=0$, I honestly have no idea whether there is or not an explicit solution. I can just tell you I don't see an obvious solution...